# Compose a pipeline with other pipelines

Tags: dagster

I am currently trying to choose between numerous workflow frameworks. I need an important feature which is workflow composition.

I found nothing on the documentation even in the [API reference](https://docs.dagster.io/_apidocs/pipeline) or [advanced tutorial](https://docs.dagster.io/tutorial/advanced_pipelines).

So my question is : Is it possible to compose pipelines ? i.e. To build some DAGs with already written ones. There is maybe some workarounds but I am interested by its native integration.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking for the composite solid abstraction, which lets you compose sub-DAGs. https://docs.dagster.io/tutorial/advanced_solids#composite-solids https://docs.dagster.io/_apidocs/solids#composing-solids

Comment: If I understand well, you can put solids inside composite solids like pipelines, and build complex pipelines with it.

But you can't just reuse an old pipeline into a new one tough.

Comment: This is going to change significantly starting in Dagster 0.12.0, where we are going to make APIs public that should make pipelines easier to compose.

Comment: This is now completely outdated -- you should be thinking about using the new asset APIs in Dagster 1.0